# list indices must be integers or slices, not dict in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I just want to iterate through the list of JSON data which I get in the payload but getting an error as `list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`

payload:

```
  [{"AuditorId":10,"Agents":"sa","Supervisor":"sa","TicketId":"58742","QId":150,"Answer":"Yes","TypeSelected":"CMT Mails","Comments":"na","TicketType":"Regularticket","Action":"na","AuditSubFunction":"na","AuditRegion":"na"},{"AuditorId":10,"Agents":"sa","Supervisor":"sa","TicketId":"58742","QId":151,"Answer":"Yes","TypeSelected":"CMT Mails","Comments":"na","TicketType":"Regularticket","Action":"na","AuditSubFunction":"na","AuditRegion":"na"}]
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):

    for ran in request.data:
        
        auditorid = request.data[ran].get('AuditorId')
        ticketid = request.data[ran].get('TicketId')
        qid = request.data[ran].get('QId')
        answer = request.data[ran].get('Answer')
        sid = '0'
        TicketType = request.data[ran].get('TicketType')
        TypeSelected = request.data[ran].get('TypeSelected')
        agents = request.data[ran].get('Agents')
        supervisor = request.data[ran].get('Supervisor')
        Comments = request.data[ran].get('Comments')
        action = request.data[ran].get('Action')
        subfunction = request.data[ran].get('AuditSubFunction')
        region = request.data[ran].get('AuditRegion')
       
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@ticketid=%s,@qid=%s,@answer=%s,@sid=%s,@TicketType=%s,@TypeSelected=%s,@agents=%s, @supervisor =%s, @Comments=%s, @action=%s, @subfunction=%s, @region=%s',
         (auditorid,ticketid,qid,answer, sid,TicketType, TypeSelected, agents, supervisor, Comments, action, subfunction,region))
        return Response(True)
```

Comment: directly use `ran.get('AuditorId')` instead of `request.data` inside the for loop.

Comment: I have tried your approach only the first list got saved and received an error for other `lists str object has no attribute` and showing error in this line `auditorid = ran.get('AuditorId')`

Comment: If the first one saved the other failed could it be that your payload is corrupted or inconsistent? Technically all the elements of the array should be dicts to @VishalSingh's suggestion should work for all elements in the array

Comment: The 2nd failed because the return is inside the for loop.

Comment: there is no payload corrupt .The dicts are inside the list so it just printing the first list nit the entire list @Artisan

Comment: Even When I return it outside the for loop as well I still facing the same issue

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby has the right answer

Answer (score 2):

I ran this code on my machine and it works for the payload you provided.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):

    for ran in request.data:
        auditorid = ran.get('AuditorId')
        ticketid = ran.get('TicketId')
        qid = ran.get('QId')
        answer = ran.get('Answer')
        sid = '0'
        TicketType = ran.get('TicketType')
        TypeSelected = ran.get('TypeSelected')
        agents = ran.get('Agents')
        supervisor = ran.get('Supervisor')
        Comments = ran.get('Comments')
        action = ran.get('Action')
        subfunction = ran.get('AuditSubFunction')
        region = ran.get('AuditRegion')
```

If it doesn't then content of request.data must be different then payload you shared in original post